# How do I draw this on latex(overleaf)?

Tags: diagrams

I'm new to drawing in latex, how do I draw this shape(with the text inside of it)?
[image]

There is circles in a circle, each circle has an arrow(preferred curved), to the next circle. And inside each small circle we have $h^*$. And I need $H$ near the 'front' circle, $g_1 H g_1^{-1}$ near the second one, and so forth.
After the fifth circle( $g_4 H g_4^{-1}$) I need a curved arrow to 3 dots, then another curved arrow to the first circle.
It would be great if the drawing would be to the dimensions of third of an A4 paper.
Thank you!

## Edit

People asked for my try-out so here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw[fill=none](0,0) circle (3.0);
\draw[fill=none](1,2) circle (0.5);
\draw[fill=none](1,-2) circle (0.5);
\draw[fill=none](2,0) circle (0.5);
\draw[fill=none](-1,2) circle (0.5);
\draw[fill=none](-1,-2) circle (0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, I don't know how to draw those curved arrows, the dots, and how to manually write the $h$'s and $g_i H g_i^{-1}$'s.

## Edit(2)

People have helped me with the design, but when I uploaded the code to a new document, it showed me the following.
[image]

And I have 2 questions:
The first one is why it doesn't show me a proper drawing of the code?
The second is why my "xcolor" package has a LaTeX error now?

Comment: Can you edit your code so it is ready to compile?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please read the [introductory material](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for this site. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to pose a new question for your edit.

Comment: Btw, I'd be nice if you accept an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: @Gargantuar I dont want to accept an answer yet because my question is not answered(fully)

Comment: There are several answers, but now information why you think, that no one does answer your question fully. So how should we know, that is missing in your opinion? BTW: Please always focus to one question. Questions with more than one questions are usually closed.

Comment: Hi @cabohah. After someone gave me an answer, I tried to compile it, but it didn't work. You can see that it gave me some strange drawing under "EDIT 2". I just need to fix it, and thats' taht

Comment: The screenshot is useless. If you get an error message, when you run LaTeX, copy the error message from the log file as code. If packages are missing, install them.

Comment: @cabohah That's the problem, there is an error message but not about the code. By OVERLEAF, the code runs fine but for some reason this is the drawing it's giving me

Comment: "An error message" is not enough information to help. Please show the error message. And please also show the code, that results in the error message. Do not use screenshots for code or error message, but copy the code and error message and mark both as code. And because all of the shown examples in the answers do work and therefore should answer the original question, please do it using a [follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117/277964) instead of changing the question multiple times after already getting answers to the original question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a basic attempt. The values `bend left=30` and `looseness=0.75` are done by experimentation (I overlayed a circle of radius `2` and tried a few values). You can simply scale this by adding `[scale=...]` as an optional argument to `tikzpicture`, i.e. directly behind `\begin{tikzpicture}`. I hope that you don't want the three dots on the last arrows exactly as you described; I just used a dashed one.

```latex
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle[radius=4];
    \node[draw, circle, label=above:\(H\)] (0) at (90:2) {\(h^*\)};
    \foreach \i [remember=\i as \j (initally 0)] in {1,...,4} {
        \node[draw, circle, label=90-72*\i:\(g_\i H g_\i^{-1}\)] (\i) at (90-72*\i:2) {\(h^*\)};
        \draw[->] (\j) edge [bend left=30, looseness=0.75] (\i);
    }
    \draw[->] (4) edge [bend left=30, looseness=0.75] (0);

    % added three dots
    \draw[white, thick] (116:2) arc[start angle=116, end angle=136, radius=2];
    \foreach \i in {0,1,2}
        \filldraw (121+5*\i:2) circle[radius=0.4pt];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update:** Although quite a hacky solution, I have simply overdrawn some part of the last arrow in white and placed three dots on an imagined circle. The middle dot is halfway between the two nodes, and each dot is five degrees appart.

Comment: It really helps, but I do want the 3 dots and not the dashed lines, because of 2 things. one of them is for my drawing(for the paper) and second thing is that I want to understand how to write it myself - hope you can help me with that, if it's not much trouble.

Comment: @ArielFishbein Instead of `dashed`, write `dotted` to get a dotted line. (Though you won't necessarily get exactly 3 dots. Is that what you need?)

Comment: I prefer the 3 dots, but it is good to know that, thank you!

Comment: @Garganuar Can you please explain the "function" of how you 'draw' the g_i H g_i^{-1} because I dont understand it

Comment: @ArielFishbein You mean the line `\node[draw, ...`? The syntax is `label=<some angle>:<some text>`, so I calculated the angle where the text should be and then the text where `\i` runs through the values specified in the loop. The `at (...)` specifies the placement of the circle itself, and the content of the circle is then `h^*`. The options `draw` and `circle` say that I want to see the border of the node drawn, and it should be a circle.

Answer (score 4):

A variation of [Gargantuar's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/705508/47927) using another node with `\vdots` instead of a dashed line:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle[radius=4];
    \node[draw, circle, label={above:\(H\)}] (n0) at (90:2) {\(h^*\)};
    \foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {1,...,4} {
        \node[draw, circle, label={90-60*\i:\(g_\i H g_\i^{-1}\)}] (n\i) 
            at (90-60*\i:2) {\(h^*\)};
        \draw[->] (n\j) edge [bend left=30, looseness=0.66] (n\i);
    }
    \node[circle, rotate=-30, text depth=0.5em] (n5) at (150:2) {\(\vdots\)}; 
    \draw[->] (n4) edge [bend left=30, looseness=0.66] (n5);
    \draw[->] (n5) edge [bend left=30, looseness=0.66] (n0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `chains`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {chains}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=placed {at=(150-\tikzchaincount*60:2)}, every join/.style={->, thick, bend left=15}, chain node/.style={on chain, circle, thick, minimum size=8mm, join}]
    \draw[thick] circle[radius=4];
    \node[chain node, draw, label={90:$H$}] {$h^*$};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,4}
        \node[chain node, draw, label={90-60*\i:$g_{\i}Hg_{\i}^{-1}$}] {$h^*$};
    \node[chain node]{}; \node[chain node]{};
    \foreach \j in {-1,0,1} \fill (150+5*\j:1.93)circle[radius=.8pt];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) with the labels inside as in the OP sketch.  I've defined a `nice_label` macro that attempts to place the labels automatically.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
path outer_circle, inner_circle;
outer_circle = reverse fullcircle   % so it runs clockwise
               rotated 90           % ... from 12 o'clock
               scaled 100mm;        % .. and takes up 1/3 of an A4 page.
inner_circle = outer_circle scaled 3/4;

numeric n; n = 6;
path c[]; 
for t=0 upto n: 
  c[t] = fullcircle scaled 36 shifted point 8/n*t of inner_circle;
endfor

vardef nice_label(expr s, z, p) = 
  save r, t, a, b; 
  picture t; t = thelabel(s, z);
  interim bboxmargin := 4;
  path a; a = z--center p cutafter bbox t;
  path b; b = z--center p cutafter p;
  numeric r; r = 1 - arclength a / arclength b;
  draw t shifted point r of b
enddef;
                 
for t=0 upto n-1:
  if t < n - 1: 
    draw c[t];
    label("$h^{\rlap{*}}$", center c[t] + 2 up);
    nice_label(
      if t=0: 
        "$H$" 
      else: 
        "$g_{" & decimal t & "}Hg_{"&decimal t&"}^{-1}$" 
      fi, origin, c[t]);
  else:
    for dt=-1/16, 0, 1/16:
      draw point 8/n*t + dt of inner_circle withpen pencircle scaled 1;
    endfor
  fi

  drawarrow subpath 8/n*(t, t+1) of inner_circle
    cutbefore c[t] cutafter c[t+1];
endfor

draw outer_circle;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

You can compile this in Overleaf if you set the LaTeX engine to `lualatex`.  You should get a PDF that looks like this:

[image]

If you change `n=6;` near the top to `n=7` you would get this version...

[image]