# How to draw a sequance of arrow forming a specific form

Tags: arrows, drawing

How to draw a sequence of arrows as in the following picture?[image]

It is pretty clear to me how to do the stright sequence of arrows using tikz, but the cycle one is not.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Unfortunately, this is not a "please do this for me" site. If you want assistance, please show us the code you have so far and explain where you're stuck. Your code should be a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvinience. The first stright sequence of the arrows is pretty clear to me using Tikz. So, my question is really how to produce the cycle one

Comment: You might want to look at the solutions to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/705495/125871).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `chains`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, calc}

\tikzset{
    dot/.style={circle, fill, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4pt},
    myarrow/.style={-latex, shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt},
    myarrow2/.style={-latex, shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt, bend left},
    elipsis/.style={fill=white, inner sep=1.5pt, circle}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=15mm]
\node[dot, start chain=1, on chain=1, label=above:$g$]{};
\node[dot, on chain=1, join=by myarrow, label=above:$g^2$]{};
\node[dot, on chain=1, join=by myarrow, label=above:$g^3$](g3){};
\node[dot, on chain=1, join=by myarrow, label=above:$g^{t-1}$](gk){};
\node[dot, on chain=1, join=by myarrow, label=above:{$g^t=g^{t+r}$}](A){};
\coordinate(B) at ([yshift=-1.5cm]A);
\coordinate(C) at ($(g3)!.5!(gk)$);
\node[dot, start chain=2 placed {at=($(B)+({(-1)*\tikzchaincount*72+162}:1.5)$)}, on chain=2]{};
\node[dot, on chain=2, join=by myarrow2, label=18:$g^{t+1}$]{};
\node[dot, on chain=2, join=by myarrow2, label=-54:$g^{t+2}$]{};
\node[dot, on chain=2, join=by myarrow2, label=-126:$g^{t+r-2}$]{};
\node[dot, on chain=2, join=by myarrow2, label=-198:$g^{t+r-1}$]{};
\node[dot, on chain=2, join=by myarrow2]{};
\foreach \t in {-82, -90, -98} \node[elipsis] at ($(B)+(\t:1.5)$){.};
\foreach \x in {-1.8,0,1.8} \node[elipsis] at ([xshift=\x mm]C){.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```